# Difference between SQL Server Embedded Edition and SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce

What is the difference between SQL Sever Embedded Edition and SQL Server Compact Edition ?

Which would be a preferable choice for an SoC embedded device ?

Comment: You may find this useful http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Comment: It does not include details about SQL Server Embedded edition Eric. Could you help me out on that ?

Comment: Embedded edition is designed for use by operating system services and some MS products, its installed with the operating system and is not redistributable.  You would use Compact for your application, assuming its running Windows but your mention of SoC makes this unclear.

Comment: See http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/microsoft-sql-server-2012-for-embedded-systems.aspx - it is a special license of the normal SQL Server editions - what is SoC?

Comment: SoC - System on Chip